# R - splitting a column of varied string length in a data frame into multiple columns of just one character

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame like this:

```
Name     S1     S2     S3     Symbol
n_12     2.3    6.1    0      A
n_13     3.4    3.7    0      ACM
n_14     1.3    1.0    0      BN
n_23     2.0    4.1    0      NOPXY
```

And I am looking to split the last column, Symbol, into multiple columns, each with one character or nothing.

```
    Name     S1     S2     S3     Sy1     Sy2     Sy3     Sy4     Sy5
    n_12     2.3    6.1    0      A                               
    n_13     3.4    3.7    0      A       C       M               
    n_14     1.3    1.0    0      B       N                       
    n_23     2.0    4.1    0      N       O       P       X       Y
```

Thank you for any and all help with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is with `tidyr::separate` which splits a single column containing a string into multiple columns containing substrings.

```
df
  Name  S1  S2 S3 Symbol
1 n_12 2.3 6.1  0      A
2 n_13 3.4 3.7  0    ACM
3 n_14 1.3 1.0  0     BN
4 n_23 2.0 4.1  0  NOPXY
```

The `sep=` argument for `separate` accepts either a regex, or a numeric vector listing the positions in the string to split on. Since we want to split after every character, we want to give a numeric sequence from 1 to the length of the longest string (`-1`, since we don't need to split after the last character). The length of the longest string is calculated with `max(nchar(.$Symbol))`. Thanks to [Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/rich-scriven) for pointing out that `nchar` is vectorized and so doesn't need to be called with `sapply`.

We then make a character vector with the names of the columns to split `Symbol` into. In your case, we can just paste `'Sy'` to that same numeric sequence to get `c('Sy1', 'Sy2' ...)`

```
df %>%
    tidyr::separate(Symbol,
                    sep = seq_len(max(nchar(.$Symbol)) - 1),
                    into = paste0('Sy', seq_len(max(nchar(.$Symbol)))))

  Name  S1  S2 S3 Sy1 Sy2 Sy3 Sy4 Sy5
1 n_12 2.3 6.1  0   A                
2 n_13 3.4 3.7  0   A   C   M        
3 n_14 1.3 1.0  0   B   N            
4 n_23 2.0 4.1  0   N   O   P   X   Y
```

---

If you get the following error:

```
Error in nchar(.$Symbol) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
```

then it is likely that `df$Symbol` is of type `factor` (the default when creating or loading a `data.frame`) not `character`.

You can either provide `read.table` or `data.frame` with the argument `stringsAsFactor=F` to keep the `Symbol` variable from being converted to `factor`, or convert it back to `character`.

Tidyverse option (which can be inserted into the pipe just before the call to `tidyr::separate`:

```
df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Symbol = as.character(Symbol))
```

or with base R:

```
df$Symbol <- as.character(df$Symbol)
```

Comment: That's because because `Symbol` is of type `factor` not `character`. You should use the `stringsAsFactor=F` when loading/creating the data.frame, or convert it with `dplyr::mutate(Symbol = as.character(Symbol))` or `df$Symbol <- as.character(df$Symbol)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R version using `strcapture`:

```
ns <- max(nchar(dat$Symbol))
cbind(
  dat,
  strcapture(
    paste(rep("(.)", ns), collapse=""),
    format(dat$Symbol, width=ns),
    proto=setNames(rep(list(""), ns), paste0("Sy",1:ns))
  )
)
```

A late base R addition using `substring`, which loops over each of the inputs, including the start and ends of each substring:

```
dat[paste0("Sy",seq(ns))] <- matrix(substring(rep(dat$Symbol,each=ns),
                                    seq(ns), seq(ns)), ncol=ns, byrow=TRUE)


#  Name  S1  S2 S3 Symbol Sy1 Sy2 Sy3 Sy4 Sy5
#1 n_12 2.3 6.1  0      A   A                
#2 n_13 3.4 3.7  0    ACM   A   C   M        
#3 n_14 1.3 1.0  0     BN   B   N            
#4 n_23 2.0 4.1  0  NOPXY   N   O   P   X   Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R base using brute force:

```
string <- strsplit(df$Symbol, "")
ind <- max(lengths(string))
out <- data.frame(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(string, function(x) {
  if(length(x) !=  ind){
    c(x[1:length(x)], x[(length(x)+1):ind] )
  }else{
    x
  }
})))
names(out) <- sub("X(\\d)", "Sy\\1", names(out))
print(out, na.print = "")

  Name  S1  S2 S3 Symbol Sy1 Sy2 Sy3 Sy4 Sy5
1 n_12 2.3 6.1  0      A   A                
2 n_13 3.4 3.7  0    ACM   A   C   M        
3 n_14 1.3 1.0  0     BN   B   N            
4 n_23 2.0 4.1  0  NOPXY   N   O   P   X   Y
```

Answer (score 0):

for completeness sake, here is a one-line `data.table` solution, usign `tstrsplit()`. The number of columns that are to be craeted are dynamic, and based on the maximum length of `Symbol`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("Name     S1     S2     S3     Symbol
n_12     2.3    6.1    0      A
n_13     3.4    3.7    0      ACM
n_14     1.3    1.0    0      BN
n_23     2.0    4.1    0      NOPXY")

dt[, paste0( "Sy", 1:length(tstrsplit(dt$Symbol, ""))) := tstrsplit( Symbol, "" )][]

#    Name  S1  S2 S3 Symbol Sy1  Sy2  Sy3  Sy4  Sy5
# 1: n_12 2.3 6.1  0      A   A <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2: n_13 3.4 3.7  0    ACM   A    C    M <NA> <NA>
# 3: n_14 1.3 1.0  0     BN   B    N <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4: n_23 2.0 4.1  0  NOPXY   N    O    P    X    Y
```